# Where to get ServiceRuntime and Diagnostics v2.0.0.0?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-web-roles, azure-configuration

Where do I get the following references for my project:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime v2.0.0.0

Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics v2.0.0.0
```

I only have version 1.8.0.0 of these and I cannot find newer versions.

I have tried installing the SDK again, but the Web Installer just says "0 items to be installed". I assume this means my files are up to date.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have version 2.0 of SDK installed? To check, you should see the following folder `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\v2.0`. If you have that, then you can find the necessary DLLs in `ref` folder.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  The Web Platform updater is misleading.  I assumed that the latest SDK was installed.  I had to uninstall everything and reinstall again to get the latest DLLs.